# Error:(29, 34) Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but Editable! was expected

Tags: android, kotlin

```
package com.example.acer.test

import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var sharedP: SharedPreferences? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btn_add.setOnClickListener {
            sharedP = getSharedPreferences("addData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            var myEditor = sharedP?.edit()
            myEditor?.putString("product_name" , et_productname.text.toString())
            myEditor?.commit()
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "The product is saved" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


        }
        btn_get.setOnClickListener {
            et_getproduct.text = sharedP?.getString("product_name","null")
        }

    }
}
```

I need to read a string from Shared preferences in Kotlin but it is showing the following error : Error:(29, 34) Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but Editable! was expected

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method like this:

```
fun String.toEditable(): Editable = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(this)
```

and then change your code like this:

```
btn_get.setOnClickListener {
            et_getproduct.text = sharedP?.getString("product_name","null").toEditable()
        }
```

This is what I used and it works great